# Webview is zooming in

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have site that I load in the webview but no metter what im doing every thing is bigger than it has to be.
if i change the size of the font in the website, i dont see any difference in the webview.
When I open the site in Google Chrome on mobile every thing ok.

This is the code of the webview

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

The website is basicly 100% width divs one below the other.
What do I have to do to fix the problem?
Thanks

edit:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Part of Css code(not including font, colors)

```
width: 100%;
font-size: 65px;
```

Comment: Did you set the ViewPort in your HTML?

Comment: Yes, I tried with I tried without it doesnt change anything

Comment: If you could post your html I think people will have abetter chance helping (including the viewport)

Comment: Edited
by the way are you Israeli?